# Why did the data stored in Apache IoTDB cannot be recognized with the library still presented in the same machine?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Having the same Apache IoTDB directory and the same machine, I copied the entire IoTDB installation directory to another directory using `cp`, and the data in it cannot be recognized. The IoTDB library, however, is still there. I am using Version 1.3 of Apache IoTDB, is this a restriction when storing data or something else? How should I solve this problem?

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no storing restriction in Apache IoTDB for your case. Therefore, you can check related to your environment settings, for example, if your firewall setting deletes the data files of IoTDB by default.